# How to deploy Microsoft botbuilder nodejs app to azure using CLI?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am trying to deploy the [basic-bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.basic-bot) Microsoft Botbuilder sample application to azure.

I started by creating a new botbuilder node.js sample application through the Azure dashboard, and I was able to successfully follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-download-source-code?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#publish-code-using-azure-cli) to download and redeploy the application.

I then attempted to copy over the deploy scripts and .env file from the downloaded sample application into the basic-bot application, and attempted to publish using the `az bot publish` command from the link above. This successfully deployed the basic-bot application, but the deployed application now returns 500 errors. Initially, the 500 errors were caused by the "botbuilder-ai" nodejs package not being installed. I installed this package manually through the Azure console, and this error went away. But the application continues throw 500 errors, without producing a stack trace, and I have not been able to determine why.

The only [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-deploy-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) I have found that explains how to deploy the bot is specifically for C# and Visual Studio. Is there a way to deploy a bot to azure for a Node.js app using the azure CLI?

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you are using BotBuilder V4 and not V3, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using botbuilder v4

Comment: Did you get the basic-bot sample running locally in the emulator before you tried deploying it?

Comment: Yes, works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to deploy a bot to azure for a Node.js app using the
>   azure CLI?

Yes there is. You can type `az bot publish -h` for all the options available to you when publishing a bot. Here are some tips about getting it to work:

- You will need to log in to Azure with `az login`
- Make sure you've set an active subscription. Type `az account set -h` for help. Use `az account list` to see your choices of subscriptions and `az account show` to see the current active subscription
- Publishing can be easier if you set the resource group you're publishing to as your default. Unlike your active subscription, configured defaults don't reset when you log out. Use `az configure` to see your current defaults and `az configure -h` to see how to set a default resource group
- If you publish and it says `Not a valid azure publish directory. missing post deploy scripts` then you'll need a PostDeployScripts folder in your bot folder

There are some [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.basic-bot/deploymentScripts/DEPLOY.md) in the deploymentScripts folder that you might find helpful. Note that as an alternative to the Azure CLI, you can also publish from Visual Studio Code using the Azure App Service extension.

If you publish successfully and you're getting errors when you try to test in Web Chat, sometimes Azure needs a little nudging. When I checked my Channels blade it said Web Chat was encountering errors regarding missing files. I tried some troubleshooting steps and eventually got it to work without any real changes.

- Try logging out of your Azure account in the online portal and then logging back in
- Try running your code in the online code editor in the Build blade
- Try publishing again

Regarding your specific situation of trying to repurpose the downloaded source code to deploy the basic-bot sample, there are a few things you need to know. The .bot file is very important as it contains information about all the services the bot uses, but basic-bot.bot contains none of the needed information. In addition to the deployment scripts and the .env file you will also need to copy over your .bot file. However, basic-bot's bot.js expects the .bot file to contain a LUIS service named "basic-bot-LUIS" so you need to go into the bot.js code and change the value of LUIS_CONFIGURATION to the name of the LUIS service in your .bot file ("BasicBotLuisApplication" if you downloaded the V4 Basic Bot NodeJS code and kept it the same). Make sure you can get the basic-bot sample to run locally before you try to publish it.

Comment: Kyle, thanks for your reply. I failed to mention in my original post that I had successfully set up LUIS, and was able to run the app locally. I was also able to verify using the botframework-app-emulator, and by inspecting the server logs, that the server is responding with a 500 error on chat request, while at the same time the server does not appear to be throwing an error with a stack trace. Re-publishing has the same result. I would appreciate any other suggestions you could provide. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: @jbeard4 - When you say you're verifying using the Bot Emulator, do you mean you're connecting to your deployed bot's azurewebsites endpoint with the emulator? What channels have you tried the bot with? You can debug your deployed bot using ngrok: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: "When you say you're verifying using the Bot Emulator, do you mean you're connecting to your deployed bot's azurewebsites endpoint with the emulator?" Yes, correct. The deployed bot receives 500 on attempt to chat. At the same time, the web chat fails to connect. "What channels have you tried the bot with?" I don't think I set up a channel on the deployed bot. Is that necessary in order to test the deployed bot with the emulator? Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: All bots automatically get connected to the Web Chat channel. It's not necessary to connect to other channels in order to connect to the endpoint in the emulator, but it can provide you more information if the bot works in some channels. Have you tried testing the bot in Web Chat? Have you tried ngrok yet?

Comment: "Have you tried testing the bot in Web Chat?" The web chat fails to connect. It just spins forever. I assume this is because the server is returning 500 on attempting to connect. "Have you tried ngrok yet?" ngrok is for testing other channels with my local server, correct? Currently, my server works locally with the emulator, and I don't need to test other channels at this time, so I am not sure if ngrok will help me diagnose the deploy issues I am seeing with azure. If you have any tips to diagnose why the server is returning 500, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You asked how to deploy a NodeJS bot to Azure using the CLI. Since I fully answered that question, would you mind marking the answer correct and giving me some upvotes? I think it would be best to ask a new question about the 500 errors specifically.

Comment: I see your point, and I appreciate your help answering my questions, but as I am unable to successfully deploy the botbuilder example, I am unable to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You have stated that you have deployed the bot successfully. The 500 errors do not seem to be a deployment issue, and this is a question about how to deploy a NodeJS bot to Azure using the CLI. You will need to ask a new question with more information about the steps you've taken as I am currently unable to reproduce the errors. Perhaps there is a problem with your Azure subscription

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181505/discussion-between-jbeard4-and-kyle-delaney).